# Client OData Patch without retrieving object first?

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I am using a C# OData 4 client as described here:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-client-app

I have a product class and it has an Id, Name, Price and Category. I'd like to do something like:

```
        var product = new ProductService.Models.Product { 
          Id = 2,
          Price = 4
        };

        container.AttachTo("Products", product);
        container.UpdateObject(product);
```

So that I can update only the price property and ignore all the rest of them. I can see that this won't work because Name and Category are Created as null when Product object is created so they will be sent in the resulting request as null.

Is there a way of doing this without first retrieving the object that I want to update? (I'm guessing that I need to go down the HttpClient route).

Comment: Just curious why you don't want to retrieve the object first?

Comment: @QianLi. It's another trip to the database when exactly the same query will be run inside the PATCH method itself. My application will be an MVC one so will be stateless so if I'm editing a record it will not keep the clean version in memory. To do something like the above will be simpler too. Can you think of good reasons to retrieve the object first in this case?

Comment: Do you want to merge the properties (PATCH) or replace the entity (PUT)?

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to use HttpClient directly:

```
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), requestUri);
        request.Content = new StringContent(@"{{""@odata.type"":""#ProductService.Models.Product"",""Price"":3000}}");
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage  response = new HttpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
```